# Links to Images in CSS with Wicket

Tags: css, wicket, wicket-6, wicket-1.6, wicket-7

I'm including a CSS file in the head of my wicket page (wicket 1.6) using `<wicket:link>` tags and it loads fine.

However links to images in my css e.g `background-image: url(xxx/xxx/pic.png);` wont load.

How do i get wicket to recognise the links to my resources(images) in my css file and change them like when i include `<wicket:link><img src="xxx/xxx/pic.png"></wicket:link>` in my HTML.

Comment: are you sure that the css file loaded fine ? check the console for not found file erros please

Comment: yes all my normal styling works just the images don't load. the problem is that my image folder is not in the same directory as my pages folder. I was just wondering if there was a fix whereby i could keep the two folders seperate.

Comment: check this also http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Images-referencing-in-CSS-with-Wicket-td3569363.html   the images have to live next 
to the css file

Comment: @AhmedGamal please convert your comment to an answer :)

Comment: @RobAu i wrote  it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images have to live next to the css file, i.e. be in the same directory.

check the following link :
 http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Images-referencing-in-CSS-with-Wicket-td3569363.html